# How do you share privileged information with a docker container deployed as a worker on elastic beanstalk?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a file containing privileged information (private/public keys, etc) which I don't want to commit to my github repository but is required to run my data processing app. I'm using elastic beanstalk to deploy this application as a docker container to an EC2 instance.

Trying to stay away from hacking something together with environment variables. I've seen that using a separate data container and attached data volume might be the proper way to do this. I haven't been able to get this working properly at this point. I'm also considering using etcd (https://coreos.com/blog/etcd-2.2/).

Interested in knowing how other developers are going about this task.

Answer (score 0):

I forked existed docker image, included special path in every config that my app was needed. Or I create /some_dir inside docker container and create links to those dir. For example:

/etc/apache2 ---> /some_dir/apache2/

I run docker container with [external volume](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems). You can read about this ["Managing data in containers"](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/):

```
docker run --rm=true -ti -v `pwd`:/some_privileged_imformation_path my-docker-hub-user/docker-image:${OS_TYPE}${OS_VERSION}_${TAG}  myapp
```

Also I am using https://hub.docker.com/ for free to do [automate build of containers on GitHUB](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/).